# Create a pivote table/graph in Excel with Values aren't cumulated

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table

So I'm pretty new to the Pivot Tables in Excel so I may not have the basic knowledge of how it works.

I have a tables filled with information (views, rating, shares) from a webpage that is saved every 5 minutes. With the pivot table I would like to be able to make a graphic with the number of likes/views/rating for a 24h period or maybe weekly in order to find that time would be best to release content.

I am able to make a graph like I want it, but I'm having trouble with thing. The values are cumulated, as you can see in the graph below, the views are around 2000-2500 which is correct, but the Facebook Likes are them around 20-30 and the Rating is around 200. Yet the FB Likes is added to the number of views and the ratings is added to the number of views and FB Likes.

[image: Graph culminating values]

I hope you can understand my problem.

Also these 3 sets of data are added in the Values of the PivotChart field, then a box named "Values" appears in the the Legend (Series).

[image: How my data is arranged]

I don't really know how to make it so that the values don't add to themselves.

Does anyone have an idea how I would be able to fix this issue if it is possible ?

Comment: It sounds like you've chosen a Stacked Line chart, instead of just a regular line chart. Try changing the chart type.

Comment: What are the possible field values? I would expect time to be on the horizontal axis where it could be grouped.

Comment: @DougGlancy Ohh my, thanks a lot :) Didn't notice that. I feel pretty dumb now, I have been looking way to far for an answer...

Comment: I know the feeling. I'm glad I could help!